# vba to change color in photoshop

Tags: excel, vba, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to change the color of a layer using vba

Basically, I have a texture file and I want to change a layer on it based on cell values, as I need to create lots of them. The values on the spreadsheet for the color are in R G B format.

I have two versions of the PSD file (can be modified), one with a color overlay, the other one just as an adjustment layer Fillcolor.

Tried the following, and also tried to find the color property in the object, but I can't find it>

Any suggestions?

```
Sub modify_psd_files()
    'Define variables for Excel and Photoshop objects
    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wbExcel As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsExcel As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim appPhotoshop As Object 'Declare as Object to use late binding
    Dim docPhotoshop As Object 'Declare as Object to use late binding
    
    'Define variables for the file names and paths
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim saveName As String
    
    'Define variables for the layer name and color
    Dim layerName As String
    Dim layerColor As String
    Dim hexColor As String
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    
    'Open Excel file and set variables
    Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set wbExcel = ThisWorkbook 'Use the workbook executing the code
    Set wsExcel = wbExcel.Worksheets("PSD") 
    
    'Open Photoshop and set variables
    Set appPhotoshop = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")
    appPhotoshop.Visible = True 'Set to False to hide Photoshop
    
    'Loop through rows in Excel and modify Photoshop file
    For i = 2 To wsExcel.Cells(wsExcel.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
        'Get file name, layer name, layer color, and save name from Excel
        fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value 'Use workbook path as base path for file
        layerName = wsExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value
        hexColor = wsExcel.Cells(i, 3).Value
        saveName = wsExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value
        
        'Open PSD file and set variables
        Set docPhotoshop = appPhotoshop.Open(fileName)
        Dim layer As Object 'Declare as Object to use late binding
        
        'Find layer by name and change color
        For Each layer In docPhotoshop.artLayers
            If layer.Name = layerName Then
                Dim artLayer As Object 'Declare as Object to use late binding
                Set artLayer = layer
                artLayer.ApplyColorOverlay
                artLayer.adjustment.ColorBalance(0) = 100
                artLayer.adjustment.ColorBalance(1) = 100
                artLayer.adjustment.ColorBalance(2) = 100
                Exit For
            End If
        Next layer
        
        'Save modified file with new name
        savePath = Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, "\")) 'Get path from original file name
        docPhotoshop.SaveAs savePath & saveName & ".tga"
        docPhotoshop.Close
        
    Next i
    'Close Excel and Photoshop and clean up objects
    'wbExcel.Close
    'appExcel.Quit
    'appPhotoshop.Quit
    'Set wsExcel = Nothing
    'Set wbExcel = Nothing
    'Set appExcel = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with VBS, but I think you need to declare a solidcolor reference first `Dim solidColorRef
Set solidColorRef = CreateObject("Photoshop.SolidColor")
solidColorRef.RGB.Red = R
solidColorRef.RGB.Green = G
solidColorRef.RGB.Blue = B`

Answer (score 0):

I offer following solution to you and for anyone with VBA and photoshop DOM.

Use VBA knowledge to open desired PSD file in photoshop programatically, search for the solidfill layer and activate it.(this you have to do on your own) en use below solution of `chgcol()` to change color of solid fill layer.

In the solution below, photoshop javascript `.jsx` file is called from VBA. Trick is to set environment variables for which I appreciate this [link](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/passing-parameters-to-jsx-file-when-using-dojavascriptfile-from-net-c/m-p/8775195)

1. Create a text file and give it a name `changecolorfill.jsx`
2. Put following code in it and save

```
    #target photoshop

function changeSolidFillColor() {
    var rValue = parseFloat($.getenv('rValue'));
    var gValue = parseFloat($.getenv('gValue'));
    var bValue = parseFloat($.getenv('bValue'));

    if (app.documents.length > 0) {
        if (activeDocument.activeLayer.kind == LayerKind.SOLIDFILL) {
            setColorFill(rValue, gValue, bValue);
        } else {
            alert("The active layer isn't a Color Fill layer!");
        }
    } else {
        alert('You must have a document open!');
    }

    function setColorFill(red, green, blue) {
        function s2t(s) {
            return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
        }
        var descriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
        var descriptor2 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var descriptor3 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var reference = new ActionReference();
        reference.putEnumerated(s2t("contentLayer"), s2t("ordinal"), s2t("targetEnum"));
        descriptor.putReference(s2t("null"), reference);
        descriptor3.putDouble(s2t("red"), red);
        descriptor3.putDouble(s2t("green"), green);
        descriptor3.putDouble(s2t("blue"), blue);
        descriptor2.putObject(s2t("color"), s2t("RGBColor"), descriptor3);
        descriptor.putObject(s2t("to"), s2t("solidColorLayer"), descriptor2);
        executeAction(s2t("set"), descriptor, DialogModes.NO);
    }
}

changeSolidFillColor();
```

3. Open file in photoshop which will have a fill color layer and make that layer visible and active.
4. In VBA module, put following code and run chgcol() subroutine. #3f79bd is Royal blue color hexcode.

.

Thanks...

```
Sub chgcol()
    Dim rgbcol As Variant
    rgbcol = HexToRGB("#3f79bd")
    'Debug.Print "Red: " & rgbcol(0) & ", Green: " & rgbcol(1) & ", Blue: " & rgbcol(2)
    Call RunJavaScriptInPhotoshop(CDbl(rgbcol(0)), CDbl(rgbcol(1)), CDbl(rgbcol(2)))
End Sub

Function HexToRGB(hexColor As String) As Variant
    Dim r As Double
    Dim g As Double
    Dim b As Double

    ' Remove the '#' from the start of the string if it exists
    If Left(hexColor, 1) = "#" Then
        hexColor = Right(hexColor, Len(hexColor) - 1)
    End If

    ' Convert the hex color to RGB values
    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Left(hexColor, 2))
    g = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(hexColor, 3, 2))
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Right(hexColor, 2))

    ' Return the RGB values as an array
    HexToRGB = Array(r, g, b)
End Function



Sub RunJavaScriptInPhotoshop(rValue As Double, gValue As Double, bValue As Double)
    ' Create a reference to the Photoshop application
    Dim appRef As Photoshop.Application
    Set appRef = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")
    
 ' Set the environment variables in Photoshop
    Dim jsCode As String
    jsCode = "$.setenv('rValue', '" & rValue & "');"
    jsCode = jsCode & "$.setenv('gValue', '" & gValue & "');"
    jsCode = jsCode & "$.setenv('bValue', '" & bValue & "');"
    appRef.DoJavaScript (jsCode)

    ' Run the JavaScript in Photoshop
    Dim stn As String
    stn = appRef.DoJavaScriptFile("C:\path\to\your\ChangeSolidFillColor.jsx")
End Sub
```